# Show post excerpts with title and image attachment thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, image, html-lists, attachment

I am having trouble getting the image attachment to show by the title & excerpt on a Wordpress page in a list. I am using a new WP_Query to generate the list, consisting of 3 posts, from certain categories. Inside the loop, I'm trying to get the first image of each post, retrieving their image IDs with a 'get_children' array (the posts do not have featured images, so I can't use the_post_thumbnail). Using console.log, I can see that I am at least getting the image url for the first item in the list, but not for the others. And even with the one I am getting, I can't get it to display using wp_get_attachment_thumb_file(). Here's the code I have so far:

```
<div class="inner-left">
<ul class="blog-posts-ul">
<?php
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => '21,23,689,741,1589'));
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php $attachment = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ) );
            if ( $attachment ) {
                $attachment = current( $attachment );
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID );
                $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $image_url );
                echo '<script>console.log("thumb: "' . $image_url . ')</script>';
            }; ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php wp_get_attachment_thumb_file( $attachment->ID ); ?>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>          
</ul>
<?php // Reset Query
wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div><!-- inner-left -->
```

The test site is at http://testsite.humortimes.com/ if you want to have a look. Scroll down, it's formatted as 3 squares, below the 'Latest Humor Times Faux News Headlines' section. Right now, it's not formatted very well, I plan on having two columns, there's just one showing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's really maddening is that using the following I get a valid attachment id...
`$attachment_id = $attachments->ID;`
...and I'm getting a valid image url with `$image_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachments->ID );` as shown by `var_dump ($image_url);`
...and yet, the following returns 'null'. Why is that?
`$image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_file( $attachment_id ); var_dump ($image_thumb);`

Answer (score 0):

Stop using console log and start using var_dump ($image_url) ; that will print whatever you have directly on that element.

I dont quite get why you cant use post thumbnail?

Comment: I don't think that works unless you have a 'featured image' chosen, which these posts do not. Also, I tried an if statement for that in this code, (if there's a post thumbnail, use it, else, do the rest), and it didn't produce anything either, because there is no featured image. I should probably put that back in, though, just for general purpose.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of frustration, I found this [nifty function](https://pastebin.com/yFd8ar8A) that does just what I want. It queries the database to find the first image of the post, which I guess is the key I was missing. It also tests for a featured image first, so that's taken care of as well. I put the function in my child function file, and just call it when needed on a page.

If you use it, be aware you need to add `$size = 'thumbnail';` because, although her description says it'll return a thumbnail, it was returning full size images. This variable is used throughout the function, though, so you just need to give it a value.

Thanks, Amberweinberg!